# Fortran 77 array initialized with stars

Tags: arrays, fortran

I am looking over some  Fortran code and have come across this

```
INTEGER            IPIV( * )
COMPLEX            A( 10, * )
```

where the variables are declared. I know that this is an array but I am not sure what the star means in this case. I tried searching for it in Google but had no luck. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Check assumed size arrays in any textbook. Then also read about assumed shape arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The star in an array declaration denotes that the size is yet to be determined.
For example, you can use it in a subroutine to allow different-sized input arrays.
Note - this also means that you may miss some compile time out-of-bounds errors.

You may wish to read the material from Iowa State University - http://orion.math.iastate.edu/burkardt/papers/fortran_arrays.html